# Problem with changing TL-WN823N state

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, usb

I bought the TL-WN823N wireless adapter because I wanted to have a better wi-fi connection on my netbook.

At first it didn't work but after installing all the necessary software it became detectable by Ubuntu and even begun to start automatically after messing around with ip link set and rebooting.

The thing is it connects to the wi-fi alongside my built-in adapter. When I tried to disconect the old adapter in any way (either by setting it down using command line or via the GUI) the USB adapter would stop working as well and the GUI would say that both are not ready for use. ip link show said they're both down and I cannot get either of them back up unless I reboot.

I don't know if having to wireless adapters connected at once is good or not but anyways I want to know what's wrong. If you'd like me to share any outputs, just ask. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2232:1054 Silicon Motion 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2 output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [144d:411c]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn` and also `lsusb`.

Comment: I didn't paste the output of lspci -knn because it would cover the whole page. If you need a specific line or a fragment, tell me what should I be looking for.

Comment: How about: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: There's the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use the USB instead of the internal, blacklist its driver so it won't load. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ath9k"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us know how it's working.

Comment: It worked though I'm not sure that's how I want it... If I don't have the adapter I'll have to "unblacklist" the driver to connect to wifi. I just want to be able to set it's status to DOWN without turning off the adapter

Comment: I don't think Network Manager is capable of doing what you are asking. You can reload the module temporarily, if needed with: `sudo modprobe ath9k`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helps. I'll mark your answer as the solution :D